# Add axes labels and title to PyQtGraph ImageView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I use a PyQtGraph ImageView to display multi-dimensional data.

What is the easiest way to add axes labels and a title to such an ImageView?

I tried adding a LabelItem to the underlying ViewBox. I assume positioning it correctly requires hacking the underlying layout. Is this the way to go, or is there an easier way?

```py
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

# make ImageView with test data
imv = pg.ImageView()
data = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: np.sin(i/16)*j/128, (512, 512), dtype=float) \
     + np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=(512, 512))
imv.setImage(data)

# add label
vbox = imv.getView()
vbox.addItem(pg.LabelItem("this is a nice label"))

imv.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: PyQtGraph ImageView example]

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

# Add Plot item to show axis labels
plot = pg.PlotItem()
plot.setLabel(axis='left', text='Y-axis')
plot.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='X-axis')

# make ImageView with test data
imv = pg.ImageView(view=plot)  # set the plot to ImageView's view  
data = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: np.sin(i/16)*j/128, (512, 512), dtype=float) + np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=(512, 512))
imv.setImage(data)

# add label
vbox = imv.getView()
vbox.addItem(pg.LabelItem("this is a nice label"))

imv.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]